# Asp.Net MVC routing diffrence in www.Mysite.com/Employee and www.Mysite.com/Employee/ while using JqGrid

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, jqgrid

I am using ASP.NEt MVC for one of my project.
In this I have Employee controller which can be called by **www.Mysite.com/Employee/** url.

Also I have used JqGrid which uses followng to fetch data

> url: "GetGridData"

While testing the same I found that

1. If i type www.Mysite.com/Employee/ in browser a call is made to

   > www.Mysite.com/Employee/GetGridData
2. If i type www.Mysite.com/Employee in browser a call is made to

   > www.Mysite.com/GetGridData

Note: the missing / at the end in second call.

How to rectify this as the chances are end user can type any of this url in browser.

Comment: Can I see your Route Mapping?  It should be set within the Application_Start method of Global.asax.cs.

Comment: It is the same which comes by default I have not modified.


routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}",New With {.controller = "Home", .action = "Index", .id = ""} )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd take a look at how you're asking JqGrid to make it's web service call - because it won't know anything about MVC's routing engine by default - and this is all happening client side.

Stepping outside of MVC for a minute, if I have a page:

> example.com/page1.aspx

And have a relative link to another page on there:

```
<a href="page2.aspx">Click here</a>
```

The browser will look for page2.aspx at the same level as page1.aspx, i.e.

> example.com/page2.aspx

If I move page1 to a new folder:

> example.com/NewFolder/page1.aspx

The browser will ask for

> example.com/NewFolder/page2.aspx

when a user clicks on the link.

The same thing is happening to your GetGridData call - these are being made by the web browser to your server based on the information it has available to it.

So if your page responds on:

> example.com/Employee

And asks for a relative request to:

> GetGridData

The browser will send that request to the same level that Employee appears to be on:

> example.com/GetGriddata

Which then fails because the routing engine can't find a route for that request.

You should look at generating the URL for the GetGridData call dynamically through the routing system, which will ensure that it's built as:

```
url: "/Employee/GetGridData"
```

---

**Final edit to add**

Forgot to mention, you should probably use the [UrlHelper Action methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action.aspx) for this:

```
url: <%=Url.Action("GetGridData")%>
```

This will generate a path to the GetGridData method on the current controller. If you need to access a different controller, or pass some values, there are overloads to help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this would not serve the purpose as if I try using Employee/GetgridData now it generates
www.Mysite.com/Employee/GetGridData when called without / and www.Mysite.com/Employee/Employee/GetGridData when called with /

Answer (score 0):

Try debugging your route:
[Phil Haack's: ASP.NET Routing Debugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx)